# pass argument in index function of controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller  name 'abc'

Now, I define a index function in it.

Now as i go to `www.example.com/abc/` or `www.example.com/abc/index` i can see my page appearing.

Now when i pass argument in that index function i would have to call it as:

```
 www.example.com/abc/index/argument
```

**So, How can i call my argument as**

```
 www.example.com/abc/argument
```

**without treating this 'argument' as public function ?**

Comment: `_remap()` will do the trick this question has been answer many times on stackoverflow see here please also with my comment below the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686389/handling-get-urls-in-codeigniter/18686593#18686593

Comment: Routing, _remap(), call_user_func_array are all good methods. Honestly though, just use "$argument = $this->uri->segment(1);". Clean, organized, and simple. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424480/how-to-pass-multiple-variables-from-url-request-in-codeigniter/16425141#16425141

Answer (score 7):

you can add routing for it in your `routes.php` file, like:

```
$route['abc/(:any)'] = 'abc/index/$1';
```

doing this will route your url `www.example.com/abc/argument` to `www.example.com/abc/index/argument`

Comment: Might cause unexpected behavior if he tried to call `/abc/index/argument` and get `/abc/index/index/argument`.

Comment: @sudhir Iam asking somethin else

Comment: @Rahul Maybe you should clarify what you are asking then, because this is looks like a good way to answer your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for [remapping](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#remapping) ?

```
public function _remap($method, $params = array())
{
    if (method_exists($this, $method))
    {
       return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);
    } 
    else 
    {
       return $this->index($method);
    }
    show_404();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to use it is to have a new controller.

In your case it should be name as `argument` that could make it work as you wish it to.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to overwrite CI_Exceptions/ function show_404  which will provide unstable solution , you could try  using another function d inside your class abc :

```
    function d (){
        $argument= $this -> uri -> segment(3);
        if ($argument) {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

and then you call it with this:  www.example.com/abc/d/argument

Answer (score 0):

You can create an init function in your controller class and then check if there any function named your first argument by function_exist() follow http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php, and then call your index function by $this->index() and pass the argument to the index function by $this->index($arg1).